# How to insert data into mysql sent by react app using sails js

Tags: reactjs, sails.js

I have a react form like this:

```
return (
    <form action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="aaa" />
     <input type="submit" />
    </form>
);
```

I have started sails js using `sails lift --port=4010`

But now, I have no idea, how to send the data to sails? What should be the URL in action?

When I open `localhost:4010` it says `Not Found`

Comment: Please show us how you tried the same without React. Maybe the problem is not related to React?

Comment: @MihályiZoltán I literally know nothing about sails js and littile about react. I searched full 2 days. Do you have any tutorial link on how to do it? I just wanna get started.

Comment: Yeah, probably not related to react. Maybe Sails JS, I think

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to generate model in Sails.js and after define attributes there.

If you bluprints is true on your config then posting your values to the "localhost:4010/{{modelName}}" must work automatically. But if you want to change the route you can override it in config/routes.js